# Get Jackson ObjectMapper in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I am writing a custom OpenApiConfigurator that adds some examples to my api dynamically.

When I add the examples using the value field of io.smallrye.openapi.api.models.examples.ExampleImpl, which is an object, the example is null in swagger-ui. It only works when I added the actual json.

To add the actual json I have to generate it from my response dto using Jackson. But how can I access the quarkus object mapper, for which I have some customisations using ObjectMapperCustomizer, if in the OpenApiConfigurator CDI is not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually possible to access the CDI container statically with `Arc.container().instance(ObjectMapper::class.java).get()`

That solved it for me.

Comment: If this solved your issue, great, however, one thing you could also do is inject your own Jackson object mapper and use it instead of Quarkus. This way, you also prevent any breaking changes between versions, when they might switch the behaviour of their object mapper.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work as is because `ObjectMapper::class.java` is not syntactically correct. Here is a version that works: `Arc.container().instance(ObjectMapper.class).get()`

Comment: It is syntactically correct for Kotlin, which is what I'm using

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the ObjectMapper, for exmaple on Kotlin:

```
@Inject
lateinit var mapper: ObjectMapper
```